# No line number in error?

Tags: magento-2.1, cli, compiler

I'm trying to run **bin/magento setup:di:compile** and I'm getting this error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'
```

There is no line number, nothing to help me determine where this error might be coming from. I don't have a PHP developer background, is there a way to figure out where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have some **syntax error** on your custom or third-party extension or in your theme.

I recommend that you:

- Use an IDE that uses a Lint (e.g. PHPStorm).
- Check the logs messages.
- Check the last commits.
- Remove all third-party modules to check if it's a module.
- Rename the optional folders and files of your custom theme to check.

When you in one of these parts above, you can go checking with less number of the files.

Comment: Right I understand that, the question is how do I figure out what line is causing the error. The CLI does not show this information

Comment: I changed my answer.